# Read a particular sheet in a xlsb file using java

Tags: excel, binary, xlsb

I tried using XSSFBEventBasedExcelExtractor class but it reads all of the data in the sheets present.
I have many sheets in Binary excel file and I want to extract one sheet. Is there a way to do that? Other approaches are welcome.

Comment: Searching for "XSSFBEventBasedExcleExtractor" did not reveal any results. Could you please check if there is a typo? It would be helpful, if you could link to any documentation that mentions this class. Could it be that this is not a publicly available class, but is actually defined somewhere else in your own code?
In any case it might help if you could provide a simple example of how your excel document looks like and what you want to achieve. In addition, you should mention which tools you are working with: are you writing a Java program? Which libraries are you trying to use?

Comment: @falk sorry typo, its XSSFBEventBasedExcelExtractor, does only read of binary excel files.